# Conditions require for ${}^nC_r$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

In basic mathematics, we know that ${}^nC_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ and ${}^nP_r  = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!}$, where $n,r \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Moreover, we need $n \geq r$. Now, my questions are as follows:

1. Does ${}^nC_r$ (and ${}^nP_r$) exist if $n,r \in \mathbb{R}_+$ given that $n \geq r$?
2. If the answer of the Q.1. is yes, then does ${}^nC_r = \frac{n!}{(n-r)!r!}$ hold true? If not, then how to evaluate ${}^nC_r$? (Similar question for ${}^nP_r$)

My understanding: I know that  $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$ where $n \in \mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Z}_{-}$.

Comment: Based on the fact that $nCr$ equals the number of selections of $r$ out of $n$ it is handsome to work with the convention that $nCr=0$ if $r\notin\{0,1,\dots,n\}$. Fortunately the Pascal-equality $(n+1)Cr=nC(r-1)+nCr$ remains valid under that convention. Also expressions like $\sum_{k=0}^nf(k)\binom{n}{k}$ can be replaced by $\sum_{k\in\mathbb Z}f(k)\binom{n}k$. This can have advantages (e.g. by proofs that use induction) because you do not have to bother about the borders anymore.

Comment: Also have a look at [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Generalization_and_connection_to_the_binomial_series).

Comment: Keywords "**extended** Pascal triangle" ; see for example [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089812219190119O)